# Azure Data Factory difference between duration time

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory, execution-time

I'm brand new with Azure Data Factory. Previously I've been working with SSIS and Pentaho. Recently I have started using this tool to create some ETL, and I've noticed some differences between the time values provided at the end of the process. So I wonder what they mean (Duration - Processing Time - Time), and especially why the big difference between Duration and Processing Time, is this difference a standard preparation time for the tool or something like that?

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the "Duration" time from the top of your screenshot, that it is end-to-end for the pipeline activity. That takes into account all factors like marshaling of your data flow script from ADF to the Spark cluster, cluster acquisition time, job execution, and I/O write time.

The bottom section of your screenshot is the amount of time Spark spent in that stage of your transformation logic, which is all in-memory data frames.

The write time is shown in the data flow execution plan in the Sink transformation and the cluster acquisition time is shown at the top.